# TypeError: overlaps() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'y1', 'x2', and 'y2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a program in python using tkinter and using the find_overlap function here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
root = Tk()

coords = 1447, 474
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1480, height=960)
frame = Frame(root, width=209, height=960)

def cords(event):
    print(event.x, event.y)

def click(event):
   canvas_id = canvas.create_line(event.x, event.y, coords)
   canvas.after(100,canvas.delete,canvas_id)

line = click

obj1=canvas.create_rectangle(605,482,247,157)
obj2=canvas.create_rectangle(802,720,270,640)

objoverlap2=canvas.find_overlapping(802,720,1082, 473)

canvas.bind('<Button-1>',line)
photo = PhotoImage(file='76.gif')
label = Label(frame, image=photo)
label.config(image=photo)
label.pack()

frame.pack(side='right')
canvas.pack(side='left')

while True:
    canvas.find_overlapping(605,156,247,482)!=line
    root.mainloop()
```

when I run this code I get this error

> TypeError: overlaps() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'y1', 'x2', and 'y2'

yet in the final loop where the error is it says. Also I don't call overlaps() during the code which is even more confusing.
update I just noticed it comes on line 39 which is weird since i don't have a line 39

Comment: Please post a full stack trace in your answer so we can see where the error is coming from.

Comment: What is your `canvas.find_overlapping(605,156,247,482)!=line` doing? Is that supposed to be an `if` statement?

Comment: yes but when I used it as one I got the same error

Comment: also I'm using a while true statement

Comment: also regarding your first comment I have now Idea what that is or how to get it

Comment: You definitely should not be callng `mainloop` in a loop. That's not _the_ problem but its definitely _a_ problem.

Comment: I ran your program with Python 3.5. It works. I suggest that you exit PyCharm and run the script from the command line. If the error persists, post the full stack trace.

Comment: a) I tried it in that and it  works too however when I change to python 3.5 in pycharm as the interpreter I get the same error.                                                b) have no idea how to get the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my error I simply mucked up the input requirements for those wondering it is the same info you put in the code to make the rectangle